# How to add paths to the apple-app-site-association file if a site has subpaths for determining locales?

Tags: ios, swift

I am having doubts regarding a particular scenario on adding paths to an association file.This is an association file for a site `www.abc.com`.Now the site starts to support localization ,For ex. `www.abc.com/en-ca` for Canada,it will display a localised Canadian site.In future more locales will be added.The rest of the paths mentioned in the association file are same (ex. `www.abc.com/path1/*` now becomes `www.abc.com/en-ca/path1/*`.How can the association file be modified in such a way that it supports `www.abc.com/en-ca` and many more locales in the future?

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "teamid.com.xxx.appName",
                "paths": [
                    "/",
                    "/path1/*",
                    "/xx/xx/path2*",
                    "/path3",
                    "/path4/*",
                    "/path5*",
                    "/path6*"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "webcredentials": {
        "apps": [
            "teamid.com.xxx.appName"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Documentation [says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/enabling_universal_links) you can use:

```
/photography/*/samples/201?/mypage
```

So in your example, it would be:

```
"paths": [
    "/",
    "/path1/*",
    "/xx/xx/path2*",
    "/path3",
    "/path4/*",
    "/path5*",
    "/path6*"
    "/*/",
    "/*/path1/*",
    "/*/xx/xx/path2*",
    "/*/path3",
    "/*/path4/*",
    "/*/path5*",
    "/*/path6*"
]
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention in the question. `abc.com` will also exist without subpath. other locales have `abc.com/en-ca` etc.`abc.com/` will have en-us as the locale.So how can the association file be modified in this scenario.?

Comment: updated answer, but you should fix that on backend to keep consistency instead of trying to do hacks on mobile

Comment: Can `??-??` be added for ex. en-ca.Hence the path becomes `/path1/*` becomes `/??-??/path1/*`

Comment: Yes.Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem, have a nice day!